# How do I get ARC to retain a delegate long enough to have it called in a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

In the following code fragment, using ARC, how do I get the delegate to live long enough to call the two method?

Current I get a compiler error

> Bad receiver type ' __autoreleasing id * '

I assume I need to do something to make ARC retain the delegate and release it when it done calling but not sure what the right thing to do is.

```
- (BOOL) requestFromURL:(NSString*)url withDelegate:( id<SimpleDataDelegate>*) delegate
{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]]
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ( error )
         {
             [delegate gotFailure:data];
         }
         else
         {
             [delegate gotResult:data];
         }
     }];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your method signature should probably be

```
- (BOOL) requestFromURL:(NSString*)url withDelegate:(id<SimpleDataDelegate>) delegate
```

instead of

```
- (BOOL) requestFromURL:(NSString*)url withDelegate:(id<SimpleDataDelegate>*) delegate
```

Notice the lack of a `*` in the first one, in the second parameter.  Try that, and see if the error goes away.  Report back if not.

Comment: Gag, what a maroon. Of course id* is confusing to ARC. Thanks for pointing out the error of my ways! The first is obviously what I meant. Clearly the issue is one of a mis-type-o.

Comment: It's not really confusing to ARC. ARC can and did handle id* absolutely fine. But it seems it was (1) wrong in the situation and (2) confusing to you.